# Capture values in an array and return the values in another sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I want to capture values in an array, from a mark sheet table in Excel, and return the values in the next sheet. I tried to make the array dynamic. I have written the code as follows:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myarr() As String

Dim lrow As Integer, lc As Integer, r As Integer, c As Integer
lrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lc = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

ReDim myarr(lrow, lc) As String
For r = 1 To lrow
    For c = 1 To lc
        myarr(r, c) = Cells(r, c).Value
    Next c
Next r

Sheets("Sheet2").Select

For r = 1 To lrow
    For c = 1 To lc
        Cells(r, c) = myarr(r, c)
    Next c
Next r

End Sub
```

I expected the array would return the values in Sheet 2 but I got no result. It does not issue an error.

Comment: You may try using the [Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value) property of the `Range` class which allows setting a value that represents the value of the specified range.

Answer (score 0):

Qualify the ranges with a specific sheet reference where possible, don't rely on Select. I expect sheet 2 was selected when you ran the code so the first `Cells(r, c).Value` would reference that sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim myarr() As String
    Dim lrow As Integer, lc As Integer, r As Integer, c As Integer
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    lrow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lc = ws1.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    
    ReDim myarr(lrow, lc) As String
    For r = 1 To lrow
        For c = 1 To lc
            myarr(r, c) = ws1.Cells(r, c).Value
        Next c
    Next r
    
    For r = 1 To lrow
        For c = 1 To lc
            ws2.Cells(r, c) = myarr(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r

End Sub
```

or more simply

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click1()

    Dim myarr
    With ThisWorkbook
       myarr = .Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
       .Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(myarr), UBound(myarr, 2)) = myarr
    End With

End Sub
```